# Swift : drawing the dots in loop

Tags: ios, swift, core-graphics, uibezierpath

I am trying to draw multiple dots in a loop by passing set of points. But not a single dot is getting drawn on view. Idea - I am parsing xml document and extracting point to draw it on view.

```
   Edit - I have updated the code with suggested changes and it is working. 

            //View Class
            class DrawTrace: UIView
{

    var points = [CGPoint]()
    {
        didSet {
            setNeedsDisplay()
        }
    }

override  func draw(_ rect: CGRect)
    {
        let size = CGSize(width: 1, height: 1)
        UIColor.white.set()
        for point in points
        {
            print(point.x,point.y)
            let dot = UIBezierPath(ovalIn: CGRect(origin: point, size: size))

            dot.fill()
        }
    }



}
 //View Controller Class  

    class ViewController: UIViewController
    {
        var object : traceDoc =  traceDoc()
        let trace = DrawTrace(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 200, height: 200))
        override func viewDidLoad()
        {

            super.viewDidLoad()
            object.collectionOfData()
            trace.points = object.tracePoints
            self.view.addSubview(trace)
        }
    }
```

Added view instance to view hierarchy that is in view controller.Created instance of DrawTrace and appended to tracepoints array.

Comment: Where do you add `trace` to the view hierarchy?

Comment: I forgot to add view instance to view hierarchy. I appreciate for the help. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is way more complex than it needs to be. One big issue is that you keep adding more and more layers each time `draw` is called.

There is no need to use layers to draw dots in your custom view. Here is a much simpler solution:

```
class DrawTrace: UIView
{
    var points = [CGPoint]() {
        didSet {
            setNeedsDisplay()
        }
    }

    override func draw(_ rect: CGRect)
    {
        let size = CGSize(width: 2, height: 2)

        UIColor.black.set()
        for point in points {
            let dot = UIBezierPath(ovalIn: CGRect(origin: point, size: size))
            // this just draws the circle by filling it.
            // Update any properties of the path as needed.
            // Use dot.stroke() if you need an outline around the circle.
            dot.fill()
        }
    }
}

let trace = DrawTrace(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 200, height: 200))
trace.backgroundColor = .white
trace.points = [ CGPoint(x: 10, y: 10), CGPoint(x: 35, y: 100)]
```

The above can be copied into a playground.

Comment: Thank you for comment. I edit the application with your code suggestions. Still no luck :(

Comment: Then you have another issue. The code in my answer works perfectly as-is in a Swift playground. What results do you actually get? Is the `draw` method even called? Are you sure you are actually creating a `DrawTrace` view and setting some points?

Comment: I have observed few things - **draw** method is not getting called. I am creating DrawTrace instance  in another class and appending points array in that class. I have edited the code in the question. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Black dotes on black view aren't visible, try to make dotes white:

```
shapeLayer.fillColor = UIColor.white.cgColor
shapeLayer.strokeColor = UIColor.white.cgColor
```

Also, in UIViewController code you are not adding your DrawTrace to views hierarchy, try in viewDidLoad:

```
self.view.addSubview(drawTraceInstance)
```

Finally, it seems that you have to iterate over array of CGPoint's. Instead of use stride, user FastEnumeration over Array:

```
for point in points
{
    drawDot(x: point.x, y: point.y,Color: fillColor, size: size)
}
```